# Multiline Comments Syntax Coloring in VIM for TeX Files

Tags: vim, latex, syntax-highlighting, tex, vim-syntax-highlighting

To my biggest surprise, the multi-line comment syntax in TeX :

```
\usepackage{verbatim} 
...
\begin{comment}
    I don't like this line anymore. Please don't print it. 
\end{comment}
```

is not recognized/dealt with by `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim` and hence not colored as a comment. Is there a VIM scripting Guru that could have a solution around, as I'm sure a lot of people have been looking for it ?

Thanks

*VIM v7.3*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little search on VIM Syntax highlighting helped me write this line of code who does almost the whole work when added to `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` (you may need to create the directory in your `~/.vim` directory):

```
syn region texComment    start="\\begin{comment}"    end="\\end{comment}"
```

My only problem is that it can't find how to disable the matching if it encounters end-of-file before end of comment environment. Anyone has a work-around ?

NB : This command does not support nesting, which is a good thing since Latex neither and  you will most likely have unmatched `\end{comment}`

Comment: The region start is independent of a possible end match, that's causing the problem. But isn't this a rather obscure corner case?!

Comment: Rather than modifying the original syntax, simply put the line in `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`

Comment: @IngoKakat : Thanks for the precision on the `/after/syntax`. With regards to your first remark, I tried things like `syn region texComment          start="/\\begin{comment}\_.*\\end{comment}/"    end="\\end{comment}"` but the fondamental problem is that if the end pattern is matched in the start pattern (which is mandatory to check it exists), I can't get it to be matched again in the end pattern.
From [VIM Doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) : the match for the end pattern will never overlap with the start pattern.

Comment: This also helped me highlight `\iffalse` blocks, by adding the line `syn region texComment    start="\\iffalse"    end="\\fi"` to my `/after/syntax/tex.vim` file.

Answer (score 2):

There are more options how to comment code (see [multiline comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44282/multiline-comment)), so this is content of mine `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`:

```
syn region texComment   start="\\begin{comment}"    end="\\end{comment}"
syn region texComment   start="\\iffalse"   end="\\fi"
syn region texComment   start="\\ifx true false"    end="\\fi"
```